# Correct way to adapt the UI to various iPhone screen sizes

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In titanium classic i do this to fit the UI to the various iPhone screen size.

```
return parseInt((Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * val) / 320);
```

Adapt the size of the objects starting from the base size that the object would have in a device with a 320 point in width.

**Test code**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var testView1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top : 0,
    backgroundColor : "#2196F3",
    layout : "vertical"
});

var testView2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    bottom: getSize(20),
    layout : "horizontal"
});

testView2.add(

    Ti.UI.createView({
        width : getSize(50),
        height : getSize(50),
        left : getSize(20),
        borderRadius : getSize(25),
        backgroundColor : "white"
    }),
    Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width : getSize(200),
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        left : getSize(20),
        text : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        color : "white",
        font : {
            fontSize : getSize(14)
        }
    })

);

testView1.add(

    Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : getSize(50),
        top : getSize(20),
        text : "Lorem ipsum",
        color : "white",
        font : {
            fontSize : getSize(14),
            fontWeight : "bold"
        },
        textAlign : "center",
    }),

    testView2

);

win.add(testView1);
win.open();

function getSize(val){
    return parseInt((Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth * val) / 320);
}
```

Result without the getSize() function

[image]

Result with the getSize() function

[image]

### **Is this a good way to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

One thing I am not sure whether you are using **"dp"** as standard unit for size system or **"pixels(px)"**, but from your first screenshot, it seems that you are not using **"dp"** size system because **"dp"** system gives you the same result without going through this **size()** method

Still, there are few things here that one needs to consider before considering the UI creation choice.

**Point #1:**

If your app UI doesn't have much content to show on visible screen, then opt to show enough big elements without going in scroll-mode.

---

**Point #2:**

If your app's UI has large content to show like a listview, tableview or other views in a scroll-view, then you should prefer to create slightly smaller elements to show more content in scrolling fashion.

---

**Best Solution:**

Stick to what Titanium does itself, choosing **"dp"** system by default & it's exactly same what you are doing with **size()** method.

Here's a link to learn more about **"dp"** system **[Titanium DIP Unit System](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy)**

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The default unit is dp, and in this example i don't change the property `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>`

Comment: This was just an example. It was to understand what method to use in general. If I don't use the getSize function, the UI would be too small on devices like iPhone 6-7-8 and iPhone 6-7-8plus

Comment: Usually that dp works well on most of the devices & sometimes it's needed to create larger UI elements. For that I would recommend to use a scale factor for such devices & on required elements rather than setting sizes for all UI elements. Just make sure that you use a more robust method for scaling so that whenever you need to rescale or use default size, you can have it done with minimum code change. To do so, you may try setting some global vars for scaling in alloy.js for high density devices.